# Calculating Solana Fees

Tags: account, data, fees

How are fees calculated in Solana ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solana Instructions have a [non-fixed fee](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/d2d4d4a240df1da4503cdf704f176c33a3a1474e/sdk/program/src/fee_calculator.rs#L112-L113) but usually 5000 Lamports [(currently)](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/596/how-are-solana-transaction-fees-calculated) A Transaction can have multiple instructions.

But Data Allocation cost is calculated

Solana [defines](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/src/solana_program/rent.rs.html#31) a constant cost as 1 byte per year and being rent exempt if you exceed 2 years. so

```
/// default rental rate in lamports/byte-year:
pub const DEFAULT_LAMPORTS_PER_BYTE_YEAR: u64 = 1_000_000_000 / 100 * 365 / (1024 * 1024);


/// default amount of time (in years) the balance has to include rent for:
pub const DEFAULT_EXEMPTION_THRESHOLD: f64 = 2.0;
```

Allocating 500 bytes will cost  `500 * DEFAULT_LAMPORTS_PER_BYTES_YEAR * DEFAULT_EXEMPTION_THRESHOLD` Lamports

Plus 5000 Lamports for the instruction

which is around ~0.007 Sol

you can do the same to calculate the fee for creating a `token account` (165 bytes) mint etc... You can automate this process with [getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption)

---

another example: [How much sol is required to mint 1000 items using sugar candy machine?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-much-sol-is-required-to-mint-1000-items-using-sugar-candy-machine/1473#1473)

Comment: `lamports_per_signatures` is [not fixed](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/2201/36)