# Read Global Settings from Core Program?

Tags: solana-program, program

In chains like eos there are system contracts that can be read from. In ethereum things like the eth staking contract can also be referenced.

Are there core solana programs that can be read from? I'm specifically interested in reading what the current transaction fee cost is per signature and or the current priority rate from within a program.

If so, what's the easiest way of viewing that information? Preferably through a block explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Solana has a number of system programs. They have the main [`SystemProgram`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/runtime-facilities/programs#system-program) and an array of other programs as part of the [Solana Program Library (SPL)](https://spl.solana.com/). If you want to find out the current price for a signature using these on-chain programs, it's no so simple, more on this [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/596/how-are-solana-transaction-fees-calculated).

However, an alternate solution that many protocols use is to use the [`getRecentPrioritizationFees`](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getrecentprioritizationfees) RPC call together with the [default](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/d2d4d4a240df1da4503cdf704f176c33a3a1474e/sdk/program/src/fee_calculator.rs#L74-L75) 5000 lamports.